# BlueMix Push Notification additional payload

Tags: ios8, ibm-cloud

I developed an iOS 8 mobile application that successfully interfaces with Bluemix push service.

Using Bluemix to generate my push notification I supply content in the Message Text field which is delivered to my application as part of the app's structure.

Using Bluemix to generate my push notification I also supply Additional Payload, but I'm not able to see this content as part of the app's structure.

Appreciate any details on how to use the Additional Payload field, its format, and how I can access that content when processing the alert within my mobile application.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Payload is an object in userInfo at the same level as aps

Rainer

Answer (score 0):

The Payload in Apple Push Notification is handled in UserInfo NSDictionary object and composed as JSON dictionary object.

Please see the following links that can provide you more information.

Apple

[Handling Local and Remote Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

[Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)

Comment: Please post the relevant bits from those links.